# Google Sheets: Pulling rows based on date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a form below...

[image: Form]

That prints responses out to the following spreadsheet

[image: Sheet]

I have this current script that takes the rows and prints them all in a google doc:

```
function saveAsDOC() {
  var fileName = "Announcements Test File";
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(fileName);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Generating file..', 'Status', 3);

  // Get the range in the spreadsheet
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange();
  try {
    var data = ws.getValues();

    // Print the annoucements in a loop
    if (data.length > 1) {
      for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
        if(new Date(data[row][2]) <= new Date()) {
          for (var col = 1; col < data[row].length; col++) {
            if(data[row][col]!=""){
              doc.appendParagraph(data[row][col]);
              doc.appendParagraph("")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

I would like to modify this script so that it only prints the rows where the 'Start Date' is today & following days up until the 'End Date'. There is *nothing* on the internet that I have found to help me, so I came here.

**Edit:** Updated with answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new Date() will give the date object of "now". Then simple comparison will do the work:

```
if(new Date(data[row][2]) > new Date() || new Date(data[row][3]) > new Date())
```

I was not sure about what you meant, but this is: if startDate is in the future or endDate is in the future.

**Complete Code**

```
function saveAsDOC() {
  // Prompts the user for the file name
  var fileName = "TEMP weggooien";
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(fileName);

  // Get the range in the spreadsheet
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange();
  try {
    var data = ws.getValues();

    // Loop through the data in the range and create paragraphs with the appropriate heading
    if (data.length > 1) {
      for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
        if(new Date(data[row][2]) > new Date() || new Date(data[row][3]) > new Date()) {
          for (var col = 1; col < data[row].length; col++) {
            if(data[row][col]!=""){
              doc.appendParagraph(data[row][col]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives me: `TypeError: Cannot read property "2" from undefined.`

Comment: Ah sorry, it should be: 
if(new Date(data[row][2]) > new Date() || new Date(data[row][3]) > new Date())

Comment: Here it works, I added the complete adjustment in my post

Comment: Okay, with your code the errors have stopped. But the problem still persists, I am working to modify the code, so you did point me in the right direction

Comment: It still prints out rows that should not be seen

Comment: Please read carefully in the text: "I was not sure about what you meant, but this is: if startDate is in the future or endDate is in the future.". Also it should have a >= sign because you said today or future.

Comment: I've clarified my problem above.